# Getting old results when iterating over sqlite3_next_stmt()

Tags: sqlite, c-api

I have a graphical interface which can display multiple SQLite query results in their own tabs. Now, I am finalizing a `sqlite3_stmt` statement when the user closes its tab, not immediately. If there is more than one tab/result, the first one gives me exactly one `sqlite3_stmt`, but the second one gives me two: the `sqlite3_stmt` from the second tab, plus the one from the first tab. A third tab would give me 3 results, and so on.

Simplified Delphi code:

```
var
    FHandle: sqlite3;
    QueryResult: sqlite3_stmt;
begin
    QueryResult := nil;
    QueryStatus := sqlite3_prepare_v2(FHandle, SQL, -1, QueryResult, nil);
    if QueryStatus = SQLITE_OK then begin
        QueryResult := sqlite3_next_stmt(FHandle, nil);
        while QueryResult <> nil do begin
            while sqlite3_step(QueryResult) = SQLITE_ROW do begin
              // store row data...
            end;
            // points to a previously prepared query:
            QueryResult := sqlite3_next_stmt(FHandle, QueryResult);
        end;
    end;
end;
```

How do I only return the statement(s) from the just fired SQL, not from an earlier one?

Edit: I just tried `sqlite3_prepare_v3`, which has a `prepFlags` parameter where I can pass [`SQLITE_PREPARE_PERSISTENT`](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_prepare_normalize.html#sqlitepreparepersistent). But that did not seem to change anything here.

Answer (score 0):

I think I overread the `pzTail` parameter in the [`sqlite3_prepare_*` functions](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/prepare.html).

So, instead of iterating over `sqlite3_next_stmt()`, I am now calling `sqlite3_prepare_v2` with the `pzTail` string from the last loop:

```
while sqlite3_prepare_v2(FHandle, CurrentSQL, -1, QueryResult, NextSQL) = SQLITE_OK do begin
    // store QueryResult for later use...
    while sqlite3_step(QueryResult) = SQLITE_ROW do begin
      // store row data for later use...
    end;
    CurrentSQL := NextSQL;
    if Trim(CurrentSQL) = '' then
      break;
end;
```

[This thread](http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/pzTail-parameter-to-sqlite3-prepare-v2-td31514.html) on nabble.com hit me into the right direction here.